# Python 'No module named' error; 'package' is not a package

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, pip

I'm trying to make a simple import and use the emailage third party library.

As per their documentation, the way to use their library is as follows:

```
pip install emailage-official
```

Then, simply import with:

```
from emailage.client import EmailageClient
```

The install works fine with pip - no errors. I double checked to see that the emailage package exists within the proper directory, and it does.

Package exists at:

```
C:\Users\aaron\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\emailage
```

This folder has (seemingly) the correct files with an `__init__.py` and everything. However, both pylint and command line interpreter throw me a 
'No module named 'emailage.client'; 'emailage' is not a package' error.

The output of my `sys.path` is:

```
[... 
'C:\\Users\\aaron\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\lib\\site-packages'
...
]
```

So the directory where emailage is installed is a part of the path... and lastly I pip-installed numpy just to test if it worked properly. Numpy installed to the same site-packages folder as emailage, and it works fine when it is imported, so I'm stuck.

I don't typically use Python much, so any and all help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

The issue was in the **naming of my file**.

I hastily named my file `emailage.py` and then tried to import from `emailage.client`.

I'm assuming that Python looked in my current directory and matched the names of the file I was working on before checking the installed third party libraries.

After renaming my file everything seems ok.

For others who run into similar problems -- **beware of conflicting naming**. Sometimes the simplest things trip you up the longest.

Comment: Quite a well-known problem in Python. Never name your scripts `email.py`, `test.py`, etc.

Comment: Agreed - my Python inexperience/rustiness definitely showing here. Completely forgot that this type of issue arises within Python.

Comment: Thanks - I ran into this very issue... being a Python Noob didn't realize it wasn't smart enough to differentiate names in different paths.  Makes sense but wasn't clear in docs.

Comment: Thanks Aaron. I wonder why Python cannot have a directory and script having the same name.

Comment: this is not developer problem but python, in other programming languages there no such problem

Comment: @phd, and `abc.py`

Answer (score 35):

I ran into something similar and the answer from OP about namespace collision is what finally clued me in.

I was using the same name for both a sub-package (directory) and a module (file) within it.

For example I had this:

```
/opt/mylib/myapi
/opt/mylib/myapi/__init__.py
/opt/mylib/myapi/myapi_creds.py        # gitignored file for user/pass
/opt/mylib/myapi/myapi.py              # base module, load creds and connect
/opt/mylib/myapi/myapi_dostuff.py      # call myapi.py and do work
```

The script 'myapi.py' imports credentials from myapi_creds.py via this statement:

```
from myapi.myapi_creds import my_user, my_pass
```

Testing the module 'myapi.py' resulted in this error:

```
$ ./myapi.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./myapi.py", line 12, in <module>
    from myapi.myapi_creds import my_user, my_pass
  File "/opt/mylib/myapi/myapi.py", line 12, in <module>
    from myapi.myapi_creds import my_user, my_pass
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myapi.myapi_creds'; 'myapi' is not a package
```

The solution was to rename `myapi.py` to `myapi_base.py` so it's name does not collide with the sub-package name.

Comment: That's the exact problem I've been banging my head against for the last weeks. A really strange and unexpected restriction for naming things. And no way to guess the problem from the error messages. Thanks for indicating this Python quirk!

Answer (score 5):

I took a look at this problem, and even though it is not exactly the same error that I encountered, it helped me solve it. I'll explain the situation I had, since I think some users might find this handy.
So, I was getting the following error log:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kemal/Programming/Python/Preference_Articulation/LocalSearch/LS_apriori.py", line 1, in <module>
    from LocalSearch.LocalSearch import LocalSearch
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'LocalSearch.LocalSearch'; 'LocalSearch' is not a package
```

The structure of my project is the following (using PyCharm):
[View of project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/keIAq.png)

The important thing to notice is that I separated my code into several folders, since it makes it more readable. Now, in the folder named **LocalSearch** I have 4 files, **LocalSearch, LS_apriori** and some 2 tests files (not relevant). When trying to run the file **LS_apriori** (which uses methods and classes from file LocalSearch) I was getting the error provided above. The code specifically is not important, and the way I handled the imports was the following:

```
from LocalSearch.LocalSearch import LocalSearch
```

The fix was simple. I renamed the py-file **LocalSearch** to **Local_Search** (just added an underscore). Afterwards, the error was gone.

So my problem was possessing a folder(package) with the same name as a file(module) inside it, which has a class inside it with the same name. Python didn't like that.
Having modules with the same name as packages inside them is fine however, I guess the class just added extra confusion.