# Python does not interpret pyomo as a package

Tags: python, conda, pyomo, glpk

I am having problems importing the pyomo environment.

```
from pyomo.environ import *
```

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyomo.environ'; 'pyomo' is not a package
```

However, pyomo does appear under `conda list`.

I know there has been an issue or two that is similar to mine. I did try to read them but haven't been able to solve it. Would really appreciate guidance.

Thanks.

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: Is there any chance that you have a file in your project source called `pyomo.py`?

Comment: @ScottMcC I have 10.11.6

Comment: @NikolasStevenson-Molnar

Yes I am painfully stupid and saved my file as pyomo.py.
Renaming the file does seem to solve the issue for now. Thank you all.

Comment: Glad it's working! I'm going to flag this as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54333865/python-no-module-named-error-package-is-not-a-package

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python 'No module named' error; 'package' is not a package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54333865/python-no-module-named-error-package-is-not-a-package)